# What should i do if i want to save more than 500 characters to an entity?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Well i tried and get an **server 500 error**.

My app must save more than 500 characters sometimes.
Any suggestion?

Using Go btw.

P.S : I always used MySQL before. So this App Engine Datastore is very new for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't specify the language, but the [documentation for Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses) says:

> For text strings longer than 500 characters (which are not indexed), use a Text instance. For unencoded byte strings longer than 500 bytes (also not indexed), use a Blob instance.

The [documentation for Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Properties_and_Value_Types) says

> Text string (short)   java.lang.String    Unicode     Up to 500 Unicode characters
>
> Values longer than 500 characters throw IllegalArgumentException
>
> Text string (long)    com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text     None    Up to 1 megabyte
>
> Not indexed

If you use another language, you should now be able to find the type to use in the documentation.

Comment: Hey what if i use multiple entities , call them all from my app , merge them all and present them as one in my app? Would be ok?? What do you say?